# Multiple events for solve_ivp

Tags: python, solver, differential-equations

I currently have the IVP solver working with an event, which looks like this:

`sol = solve_ivp(fun3, (0, tend), V, method='LSODA', events= event, args=(r_s,), t_eval=t)`

However I want the solver to check two event, not one. So I want something like this:

`sol = solve_ivp(fun3, (0, tend), V, method='LSODA', events= (event, event2), args=(r_s,), t_eval=t)`

However that doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to check for multiple events?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Or how exactly do you determine "doesn't work"? In principle, this should work.

Comment: It's correct indeed! PyCharm said it expected a different type, but the code did run when I correctly defined a second event. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works! PyCharm showed a warning, but it actually works